# Allow user to select text in ShowMessage dialog

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-xe2

I am writing a program in Delphi XE2. At one point in my program the user will be presented with output text, which I display through a simple "showmessage('The text of interest')" dialog.

I would like for the user to be able to copy and paste this text if they like to. It's not a key part of the program at all but I know that it might be nice for them to be able to do so.

At the moment, as far as I can see, it is not possible to select all or parts of the text from this type of message box, which brings me to my question: is there some way to make the message box text selectable for the user, or will I have to move on to other ways of displaying the text if I want this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pressing or simulating Ctrl+C when messagebox appears copies the messagebox title, the message and buttons captions.

Comment: You could try a non-editable edit text without the border. (And thus it's not a default "this type of message box" anymore, you'd need you create your own.)

Comment: Thanks @RawN! I know of this and it's very handy, but I doubt that my users will know that without googling... I could perhaps add it as some kind of tip but that seems a bit too much.

Comment: @Jongware, thanks, that's probably what I'll end up doing!

Comment: Agreed - if this output *must* be displayed in a modal dialog (I question whether this is the best approach, but...) then the sensible solution is a custom dialog with an extra button that says "Copy" which copies the text to the clipboard when clicked.

Comment: @J... No, it doesn't have to be a modal dialog, and maybe I should rethink that choice. It just isn't important to the program at all and I threw in a showmessage mostly for pedagogical reasons... but I'll be replacing that now, you guys got me thinking of a few alternatives. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `ShowMessage` a system message dialog is shown. This dialog does not support highlighting of individual portions of text. However, the dialog does respond to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> by placing the entire content of the dialog on the clipboard.

If you absolutely must have selection of individual portions of text then you will need to create the dialog yourself using Delphi controls.

Comment: I do really want them to be able to select individual portions so I will go for creating the dialog myself. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @MrKiloByte open Dialogs.pas and have a look how it is implemented in Delphi today, make a copy and change the things you want. If you keep the same interface you can replace the original dialogs

Comment: Weh you have you own version of dialogs.pas create a new question and I'll help you with replaceing the original dialogs